# padding-right not working

Tags: html

I am having code like this

```
        <div style="background-color: greenyellow; color: black">
        <span style="padding-left:20%">T1</span>
        <span style="padding-right:10%">2</span>
    </div>
```

currently it is showing like this. [image: current situation]
here padding right is not working. it should be such that 2 should be having 10% padded from right of this div. 
Is there any other style tag which can do give such padding from right.[image: required output]

Comment: did you consider of using margin-left rather than padding left

Comment: it is also showing same problem. right is not working in both padding and margin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

by default, inline elements are rendered left to right aligned, unless you specify `float` property for them.

That means, in a given horizontal line, first `span T1` will be rendered adjacent to the left border of the parent and then `span 2` will be rendered adjacent to `span T1`.

so, your padding-right is never being utilized, as the last span is already far away from right border, unless you make it to move right either by `float:right` or giving it a `margin`

try this:

```
 <div style="background-color: greenyellow; color: black">
        <span style="padding-left:20%">T1</span>
        <span style=" float:right; padding-right:10%;">2</span>
    </div>
```

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/px5Xn/)

Answer (score 1):

This will give the desired effect

```
<span style="float:right; margin-right:10%">2</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:-

```
<span style="float:right; padding-right:10%">2</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Good explanation by above contributors, but you can also try this:

```
<div style="background-color: greenyellow; color: black">
    <span style="padding-left:20%">T1</span>
    <span style="padding-right:10%;padding-left:60%">2</span>
</div>
```

Infact, this is about how you take the structure of your CSS, if we consider Left to Right precedence which Manish mentioned, we can also adjust our requirement by inserting a left padding of 60%.

So, this problem can be solved in both ways, if you want to adjust something in between "T1" and "2" you should use mine one, otherwise both are fine.

Hope you got it.